# How do you implement cloud solutions without incurring costs during development?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am completely new to the implementation of cloud solutions. I've just started taking AWS training courses.

But I already have a very fundamental question about the flow of development in cloud projects:
How do you go about developing solutions without incurring costs? I know that there are free tiers, but in practice you need a lot of unfree elements. Especially when working with infrastructure-as-code approaches (e.g. CloudFormation), it can happen that every time you try out the templates, costs can be incurred immediately.

Is there maybe something like a sandbox mode or how else do you go about it in practice?

Comment: CloudFormation is free. And the resources that it creates, it depends on your application.

Comment: There is no such thing. I strongly suggest setting up a Billing Alarm as first thing. This way you'll be notified if there is a cost generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the AWS Free Tier you will be billed for creating services.

The best way to keep costs as low as possible is to combing the lowest priced settings (such as instance class) with removing resources you're not using after you're complete. I understand that this will cost, however many resources are now moving to per second billing (where you normally have to pay for at least the first minute) so the cost is kept low.

Additionally when dealing with some services (such as EC2, ECS, Fargate and ECR) you can make use of spot instances to pay sometimes as low as 10% of the original cost which will help to reduce these resources.

To ensure you can recreate resources when you want them use infrastructure as code to reroll out as you need the resources (CloudFormation or Terraform are great offerings for this).

Finally be on the lookout for AWS conferences, they are a great way to pickup AWS credits for attending which will offset your bill against most AWS services.